# Android TextView Gravity BOTTOM unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, textview

My current Android project has a requirement to display multiple lines of text (maximum of 3) within a `TextView` and place the text at the bottom of the text view.

My TextView is defined as follows:-

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_title"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/other_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/span_eight"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dot"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_twelve" />
```

When the text to display is 3 or less lines the text displays as you would expect.

However when its longer than 3 lines the start of the text is truncated.

For example

"`Artificial cells, nanomedicine, and biotechnology`"

is displayed as

```
"`cine, and biotechnology`"
```

what I require is for it to display as

```
"`Artificial cells, nanom`"
```

How do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Which layout are you using?

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani I am employing a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Add this property to your `TextView` you will see Text from start and at the end of third line 3 dots(...) will be there to indicate text is more than 3 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try;

```
android:gravity="bottom|start"
```

Instead of

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: android:gravity="bottom|start" makes no difference to the displayed text. What does fix it "almost" is using  android:gravity="bottom" & android:ellipsize="end", however I do not want to have ellipsize

Comment: You may try to use external library if it works;
https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
android:gravity="start"
```

bottom value in the gravity will change the display behavior. You vary the TextView height with margin.